# How can I make this more DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just need some help in making this more DRY. Not sure if using a switch statement is the way to go...

```
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
  let emailDup = 'user already exists'
  let userDup = 'username already exists'
  if (err.response.body.includes(emailDup)) {
    this.setState({
      errMessage: errEmailDup,
      error: true,
      loading: false
    })
  } else if (err.response.body.includes(userDup)) {
    this.setState({
      errMessage: errUserDup,
      error: true,
      loading: false
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      errMessage: errDefault,
      error: true,
      loading: false
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it seem wet at the moment?

Comment: What does DRY mean?

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves "Don't Repeat Yourself".

Comment: More on DRY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself . In this case, it seems like a local for the error message would let you assign it to be any of the three possibilities, then you could setState once rather than 3 times with appropriate values for error and loading:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is easy to read and to maintain (adding more cases is easy as well):

```
.catch((err) => {
    let emailDup = 'user already exists';
    let userDup = 'username already exists';
    let errMessage;

    if (err.response.body.includes(emailDup)) {
        errMessage = errEmailDup;

    } else if (err.response.body.includes(userDup)) {
        errMessage = errUserDup;

    } else {
        errMessage = errDefault;
    }

    this.setState({
        errMessage: errMessage,
        error: true,
        loading: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary

```
.catch((err) => {
    let emailDup = 'user already exists'
    let userDup = 'username already exists'
        this.setState({
            errMessage: err.response.body.includes(emailDup) ? errEmailDup : (err.response.body.includes(userDup) ? errUserDup : errDefault),
            error: true,
            loading: false
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as well though, for readability, since I have to add other error messages, @ninjin 's solution works better.